# Installing Nest 3rd generation thermostat from Old Trane Weathertron Thermostat (Mercury one)

Tags: electrical, wiring, thermostat

Nest is not detecting Power (Rh) Showing error that power is not connected. Please help.

Installing Nest 3rd generation thermostat from Old Trane Weathertron Thermostat (Mercury one)

New stat wiring:
[image: new stat wiring]

Old stat wiring:
[image: old stat wiring]

Nest error:
[image: Nest error]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both ends?

Comment: How do i post picture?

Comment: Post them to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post links here

Comment: https://imgur.com/mS1L3nO
https://imgur.com/3G6fOsS
https://imgur.com/omHpkcx
https://imgur.com/rG6XwMH

Comment: Can you post a photo of the wiring at the air-handler please?

Comment: https://imgur.com/FG00IHv

https://imgur.com/DMsf5wl

https://imgur.com/i3Buvmd

Comment: In the junction you posted the photographs of, I take it all the connections are like-color-to-like color? We'll need photos of the wiring inside the air handler and a wiring diagram or make/model number for the air handler, by the way.

Comment: Have you tried moving the red wire to the `Rc` terminal, instead of `Rh`?  I think Nest uses `Rc` for power when working with heat pumps.

Comment: Yes. i tried moving it to Rc terminal also. Although it already have jumper inside the nest equipment which connects Tc and rh

Comment: What's the make and model of the heat pump? Can you upload a clear photo of the thermostat wiring inside the heat pump?

Comment: T (brown) wire is the common on my trane weather tron. The blue wire IS NOT used on the Nest. And x2 calls for emergency heat on the t stat.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: The nest is not showing an error.

Answer (score 1):

While you do not state if this is a heat pump unit - the wiring indicates it is..

Your **NEST screen** shows that Rc (24Volt power for Cooling Circuit) is connected and Rh (24Volt power for Heating Circuit) is not connected, yet in your picture for wiring hook up your red wire is connected to the Rh line (so how does Rc get power and show a connection?). The Nest is either reporting wrong - or you have changed something between pictures.

You can run a jumper across from Rc to Rh since you only have one Red wire. Unless your NEST configuration allows you to to do that through software - if the software does this for you when you select heat pump - I would venture the red they will have you connect to Rc and program jumper to Rh it might aut connect it as well.

You will also need to make sure you specify in the NEST system that you have a HEAT pump unit - this might be a reason Rh does not work and Rc does.

Why you have BLACK X2 to HUM (which I think is humidifier) - I don't know.
X2 is supposed to be AUXilliary Heat and would be connected to W2.

You can see my post [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/128301/why-are-the-white-and-orange-wires-both-connected-to-my-thermostats-w-terminal/128337#128337) for Thermostat wiring proper color code and also what the individual labels mean - what circuit they are for.